# How to delete/destroy my telegram api_id and api_hash

Tags: telegram, mtproto

For some reason i need to delete/destroy my api_id and api_hash.

In https://my.telegram.org/apps there is no options/button to doing this action.

And i've already tried with deleting my account from telegram
But my api_id and api_hash is still working.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this.
I found this in the Telethon documents:

> Remember that your API hash is secret and Telegram won’t let you
> revoke it.
> Don’t post it anywhere!

Source: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/signing-in.html