# How to delete Telegram app (api_key & api_hash)?

Tags: telegram, api-key, tdlib

I am trying to delete telegram api_key & api_hash, or atleast reset api_hash.

But i can't find the option to do this in this page `https://my.telegram.org/apps`.

Does anyone know how to delete or reset api_hash of telegram api app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete/destroy my telegram api\_id and api\_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259561/how-to-delete-destroy-my-telegram-api-id-and-api-hash)

Answer (score 3):

Someone has answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259561/how-to-delete-destroy-my-telegram-api-id-and-api-hash#answer-66263448). You can not revoke api_key now.

But you can try to send e-mail to `recover@telegram.org`, to describe your problem or ask for help.

Ref: https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id#using-the-api-id